# Как в join выбрать 1 строку с максимальным значением поля, вычесть из нее 1, и соединиться с третьей таблицей по другому полю из полученной строки?

Tags: mysql

В базе mysql Есть 3 таблицы

1. Список пройденных анкет `poll_questions_answers_data`
2. Список ответов по ним `poll_questions_answers_storage`
3. Список вопросов со всеми настройками `poll_questions_base`

Мне нужно вывести список анкет, с предпоследним ответом и текстом вопроса по нему. (ответы просто в формате 1,2 3 не принципиально)

Запрос почти написал.

Хотел вставить скрины, но ошибка поэтому продублирую сам запрос

```
$user_ankets = db_query("
    SELECT q_a_d.*, node.created AS created, q_a_b.name
    FROM poll_questions_answers_data AS q_a_d
    LEFT JOIN poll_node AS node ON q_a_d.nid = node.nid
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(q_a_s.qasid)-1 AS qasid, q_a_s.qbid AS qbid, q_a_s.nid AS nid
        FROM poll_questions_answers_storage AS q_a_s
        WHERE q_a_s.uid = :uid AND q_a_s.status = 1
    ) AS q_a_s_clone ON q_a_d.nid = q_a_s_clone.nid
    LEFT JOIN poll_questions_base AS q_a_b ON q_a_s_clone.qbid = q_a_b.qbid
    WHERE q_a_d.uid = :uid
    ORDER BY q_a_d.qadid DESC
", array(
    ':uid' => $user->uid,
))->fetchAll();
```

Вот такое вычитание как выше выводит всегда первый вопрос. То есть возвращается имя первого вопроса q_a_b.name

Мне же нужно получить идентификатор того вопроса, у которого идентификатор ответа с учетом вычета на 1, меньше максимального в таблице ответов q_a_s.qasid.

То есть если в таблице ответов, максимальный идентификатор ответа q_a_s.qasid = 120.

То мне нужно получить, строку с идентификатором q_a_s.qasid = 119, в ней найти идентификатор вопроса q_a_s_clone.qbid и по нему связаться с таблицей вопросов q_a_b (q_a_s_clone.qbid = q_a_b.qbid)

Но при этом, если выведу не `q_a_b.name` a `qasid`

Вот так `SELECT q_a_d.*, node.created AS created, qasid` то в массиве будет именно 119. Значит сама математическая операция срабатывает

Comment: А как у вас так оказалось, что вы уверены в неразрывной нумерации поля qasid. Если максимальный 120 обычно в БД нет гарантии, что 119 то же есть

Comment: @Mike  qasid это автоинкремент, если анкета завершена на первом вопросе и то он является максимальным, соответственно, у меня просто выборка не произойдет и предыдущего ответа я не увижу. Зачем мне нужен предыдущий ответ? - дело в том что если анкета завершается досрочно, то последний ответ дается на вопрос, почему завершили досрочно, но в списке я хочу выводить именно, тот вопрос ответ на который был последним. А так у меня в списке всегда бы выводился вопрос "почему решили завершить досрочно"

Comment: но вы же берете максимальный -1 я так подозреваю этим вы хотите получить предпоследнюю запись. Атоинкремент кстати не гарантирует безразрывную нумерацию, он _имеет право_ выдать после 1 сразу 100, он гарантирует только, что id будут расти. И есть масса случаев в которых он пропускает id. Не говоря уже о том, что какие то записи могли просто удалить

Comment: @mike может и так не слышал о таком, и в живую не встречал пока что)) у меня пропускаться точно не будет, все записи добавляются последовательно, и не удаляются, для удаления у меня есть после status=0

Comment: И кстати `SELECT MAX(q_a_s.qasid-1) AS qasid, q_a_s.qbid AS qbid, q_a_s.nid AS nid` без group by, соответственно максимум из всей таблицы, то же может доставить массу неприятностей. потому что он не гарантирует, что qbid и nid будут относиться именно к записи с максимальным qasid. Можно такой запрос расценивать как "дай случайное значение из этих полей"

Comment: Но ведь у меня написано дополнительное условие? разве он не должен выбрать максимальную запись, именно из тех строк которые прошли через where?

Comment: Просто попробуйте вставить запись с какой нибудь ошибкой из за которой запись не вставиться. например с NULL в поле где его быть не может или с превышением длины текстового поля или с нарушением внешнего или уникального ключа. И гарантированно получите пропуск автоинкремента, потому что номер резервируется до попытки вставки. Все таки выборка с `order by qasid desc limit 1,1` гораздо лучше для получения предпоследней записи.

Comment: Максимальную - да, из тех что прошли where, но qbid и nid могут быть от другой записи, так же прошедшей эти условия

Comment: @mike сделал как вы сказали, переписал ответ на свой вопрос, но возникла проблема что нужно еще и добавить условие.. в итоге ответ превратился в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

По комментарию сделал следующее, все работает отлично, но возникла проблема.

Если анкета не завершена, то нужно выводить не предыдущую запись, а как раз последнюю, чтобы смотреть на каком шаге сейчас анкета.

Статус завершения анкеты хранится в этом поле q_a_d.status и может быть равен 0-в процессе, 1-завершена досрочно, 2-полностью пройдена

Так вот, если статус равен 1 то мне нужно получать предыдущую запись, во всех других случаях нужна последняя нашел что можно врое как писать условия

```
    $user_ankets = db_query("
        SELECT q_a_d.*, node.created AS created, q_a_b.num
        FROM poll_questions_answers_data AS q_a_d
        RIGHT JOIN poll_node AS node ON q_a_d.nid = node.nid
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT q_a_s.qasid AS qasid, q_a_s.qbid AS qbid, q_a_s.nid AS nid
            FROM poll_questions_answers_storage AS q_a_s
            WHERE q_a_s.uid = :uid AND q_a_s.status = 1
            ORDER BY q_a_s.qasid DESC 
            LIMIT 1,1
        ) AS q_a_s_clone ON q_a_s_clone.nid = q_a_d.nid 
        LEFT JOIN poll_questions_base AS q_a_b ON (case when (q_a_d.status = 1) then q_a_s_clone.qbid else q_a_s_clone.qbid = q_a_s_clone.qbid+1 end) = q_a_b.qbid
        WHERE q_a_d.uid = :uid
        ORDER BY q_a_d.qadid DESC
    ", array(
        ':uid' => $user->uid,
    ))->fetchAll();
```

Написал вот так, ошибок нет, но возвращается все равно -1

Comment: У вас что то странное. right join говорит что в poll_node запись быть обязана, а в q_a_d не обязательно. Но условие q_a_d.uid= в where говорит что запись в q_a_d таки должна быть. зачем тогда right ? в нем либо нет смысла и это ничего не значит, либо смысл все таки подразумевался и тогда это проблема.

Comment: Да там дополнительное условие еще было right нужен был потому что на это условие как раз проверялась правая таблица, и если оно не выполнялось то должна была возвращаться пустота. Но пока убрал лишнее

Comment: И кстати еще интересно, что если ответ всего один а анкета при этом завершена (в ней видимо был один вопрос). предпоследней записи точно нет

Comment: Можно что нибудь вроде этого попробовать https://pastebin.com/nzHsNaYz Но мне кажется с переменными в подзапросе могут быть проблемы и лучше было бы для нумерации строк использовать row_number(), но он доступен только в 8 версии